# Custom ContextLoaderListener class is not working in Websphere

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere, web.xml

Custom ContextLoaderListener class is not working in Websphere and it is throwing the below error. The same is working fine in Tomcat, JBoss, Weblogic.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

My custom context loader class looks like below:

```
public class CustomContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
     //implemented contextInitized() and contextDestroyed() methods
}
```

In web.xml, added as below:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.comp.app.context.CustomContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this error?

Update: Found the below error in logs.

```
 00000026 DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name configMgr: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: xxxx; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [xxxxxx] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Please post the whole `web.xml` file. What version of the Servlet API are you using?

Comment: And please add the code for the custom implementation.

Comment: My web.xml contains the below version info. `<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">`

Comment: My custom implementation class has code to initialize some required properties and starts jobs, etc., and it also has call to super implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of my problem. Here the problem is not with Custom Context Loader. I have not configured JNDI name properly in my spring application context xml file. Now Custom class is working fine and error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `ContextLoaderListener` is its `contextInitialized()` method initializing and registering the `WebApplicationContext` in the `ServletContext`. If you have overriden this method without calling the `super` implementation, it won't register any `WebApplicationContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My custom class has the call to the super implementation of `contextInitialized()` method, but placed at the end of the method, not in start of the method (my code is required for context initialization).